# How to add text in Help in Main bar in mac application

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar

As i'm new to mac app development can anyone help me to solve my problem.

In my mac app i want to add help document the Help Option in the menu bar, can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main options.  You can either [create a help book bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html) for your application or you can create your own method and link it to the menu selection.  (It's not clear from your question exactly how you want to display your "help document".)

Comment: @Philips i want to display it as an word document.

Comment: In that case, use option #2: link the action in the help menu to your own method (in the application delegate, probably).